# Use JQuery UI styles on other HTML elements

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

We use a JQuery UI theme and also have a `<fieldset>` with this CSS: `fieldset {border:1px grey solid}`.

Instead of specifying `grey` for the border, how can we use a color/style that is provided with theme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to add one of the predefined UI classes to your frameset. Ideally, you want to do this in a 'semantic' way as possible, rather than just 'borrowing' whatever class seems to match your styles best.

Looking at the jquery-ui.css file, I'd say you could go with `ui-widget-content` - that seems most appropriate.